# Custom JsonConverter does not call ReadJson

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to implement a custom JsonConverter for a struct, but I'm having a hard time getting it to work. I have previously implemented a custom converter for another class and that one works flawlessly, I thought I did the same thing for this one but the ReadJson method of my converter is never called.

This is the class:

```
public class TransformMatrixConverter : JsonConverter
{
  public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
  {
    return typeof(TransformMatrix).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
  }

  public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public override bool CanWrite
  {
    get { return false; }
  }

  public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

And below is how I use it in my Item class. You can see my other converter, which works fine.

```
public static Item FromJSON(string json)
{
  JsonConverter[] converters = { new LineConverter(), new TransformMatrixConverter() };
  return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings()
  {
    Converters = converters
  });
}
```

What happens: the CanConvert method of my converter is called and correctly returns true when appropriate; however, the ReadJson method is never hit, I have a breakpoint there and also that exception is never thrown. I have verified that the CanRead property of the converter is true. I am at a loss here, any ideas?

Comment: You're missing some key details.  What does the JSON look like and what does the definition of `Item` and `TransformMatrix` look like?  Based on the information you've given I cannot reproduce the problem.  A bare-bones minimum program with made-up JSON and class/struct definitions hits the exception in the TransformMatrixConverter.  Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IEexiW

Comment: Did you verify that Json.NET ever actually passes `typeof(TransformMatrix)` to your `CanConvert(type)`?  Or did you just verify that 1) it is called, and 2) when called manually with `typeof(TransformMatrix)` it returns `true`?

Comment: @BrianRogers Ahh thank you! You made me go over another part of my code which had the problem! I think I solved it now - the TransformMatrix I thought I was deserializing was just a read-only property.

Comment: @user1846231 You should consider adding your solution as an answer to your question so that others know the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it with the help of Brian, the problem was unrelated to the code above - the TransformMatrix I thought I was deserializing was just a read-only property. The solution I used was to expose another property which the deserializer can write.